# Would Fire and Cold Breath weapons used on the same round cancel each others?

Tags: dnd-5e

Assuming we have a white and a red dragon, or the Tiamat, would a Cold and Fire breath targeting the same area cancel each others?

It seems to me that a breath weapon is fast but not totally instant, so it takes a little time to do damage and the breathing has to reach the target. So would two breaths cancel each others or at least repulse each other at the point they meet?

Comment: If you want a *plausible* answer, rather than a rules answer, the World Building SE might be a good place to post.

Answer (score 8):

Since the text of breath weapons does not say they are canceled out or repulsed by other breath weapons, no they do not cancel or repulse each other.

However, a DM could decide to run it this way for dramatic effect. It would mostly be a descriptive thing though, because breath weapons do only last an instant during a given turn.

A character caught near the middle should get hit by both if the areas overlap, but the DM can change the behavior if desired.

Comment: FWIW comment: For a dip into a more simulationist ruling, the temperature extremes hitting the character at the same time, or close together, would be a shock to the system, and thus do more damage.  (See what happens to glass when you heat it and then chill it, for example: can shatter).